# Tourist visa to the US but work for foreign country?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, work

My friend is staying with me in the United States for 2 months. He is visiting me from Japan. He wants to work for Japan while being a tourist here to help me pay the bills. He found an online job, which is located in Japan. Can he do this online job while physically present here in the United States, for Japan, get money deposited into his account from the company physically present in Japan, and then use that money here inside the United States without breaking any employment laws?